# p:summaryRow não funciona com p:columns

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eu tenho uma página JSF com um `p:columns` para mostrar dados analiticamente e um `p:summaryRow` para mostrar o resumo.

Acontece que dentro do meu `p:summaryRow`, eu tenho um `p:columns`, porque eu não posso prever quantos resultados terei, então eu preciso usar colunas dinâmicas.

Mas, quando eu carrego a página, esse `p:columns` não é mostrado. Na verdade, o método de onde eu pego os dados no Bean nunca é chamado.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{storeBean.segmentsByStore}" var="segmentsByStore"
                     sortBy="#{segmentsByStore.segment}">
<p:summaryRow>
    <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
        <h:outputText value="TOTAL OF #{segmentsByStore.segment}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:columns value="#{storeBean.totalStoreSaleDates}" var="saleDate">
        <h:outputText
                value="#{storeBean.totalStoreSales.get(saleDate).get(segmentsByStore.segment).value}">
            <f:convertNumber type="currency"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:columns>
</p:summaryRow>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: O método não chamado é o storeBean.segmentsByStore ?

Comment: É o `storeBean.totalStoreSaleDates` e o `storeBean.totalStoreSales`. O que está dentro do `p:columns`.